# animación CSS, HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

me podrían facilitar algún tutorial, libreria, codigo o herramienta para realizar una animación exactamente igual a esta:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jzoom/images/master/layout2.gif?fbclid=IwAR1scJKCGIrlhgFc-Z4g4gLfahiQikwPFKQ6HvpYpA7B3rYYMv88Yo3xC38

muchas gracias

Comment: https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/RwwqqJE

Comment: @carolina-velasquez recuerda marcar tu respuesta correcta

Answer (score 1):

Estimada, lo que buscas se llaman "Sliders" y existen en todo tipo de lenguajes, te comparto un link hecho en Bootstrap 4

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_16e7f6e179b%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_16e7f6e179b%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22285.9140625%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EFirst%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_16e7f6e179c%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_16e7f6e179c%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22247.3125%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3ESecond%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20800%20400%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_16e7f6e179c%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_16e7f6e179c%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22800%22%20height%3D%22400%22%20fill%3D%22%23555%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22276.9921875%22%20y%3D%22217.7%22%3EThird%20slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Te dejo ese Snippet con el código de ejemplo y el [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) de donde está el ejemplo, saludos!

Comment: Edité el comentario y añadí el ejemplo, tienes razón, fue bien precaria la respuesta. Saludos